# Asyptote Unofficial package arrows_pi.asy not respecting order of points for vertical arrows

Tags: asymptote

For example

```
draw((0.5,0)--(.5,1), EdgeArrows(), p=red);
```

and

```
draw((0.5,1)--(.5,0), EdgeArrows(), p=red);
```

give identical results.
Website: [corrected after this question](http://git.piprime.fr/?p=asymptote/pi-packages.git;a=blob;f=arrows_pi.asy;hb=5f86ed1e08adb6349d0f9c262d8c52afe993c477)

original package (before corrections based on this question):

```
// Copyright (c) 2007, Philippe Ivaldi.
// Last modified: Mon Dec 31 15:29:19 CET 2007
// This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at
// your option) any later version.
// This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
// WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
// General Public License for more details.
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
// Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
// 02110-1301, USA.


arrowhead EdgeHead()
{
  arrowhead oa;
  oa.head=new path(path g, position position, pen p=currentpen, real size=0,
                   real angle=arrowangle)
    {
      if(size == 0) size=arrowsize(p);
      bool relative=position.relative;
      real position=position.position.x;
      if(relative) position=reltime(g,position);
      path r=subpath(g,position,0.0);
      pair x=point(r,0);
      real t=arctime(r,size);
      pair y=point(r,t);
      path base=y+2*size*I*dir(r,t)--y-2*size*I*dir(r,t);
      path left=rotate(-angle,x)*r;
      real[] T=arrowbasepoints(base,left,r);
      pair denom=point(right,T[1])-y;
      real factor=denom != 0 ? length((point(left,T[0])-y)/denom) : 1;
      path left=rotate(-angle,x)*r;
      real[] T=arrowbasepoints(base,left,r);
      return subpath(left,0,T[0])--y--cycle;
    };
  return oa;
}

arrowhead EdgeHead=EdgeHead();

arrowhead EdgeHookHead(real dir=arrowdir, real barb=arrowbarb)
{
  arrowhead oa;
  oa.head=new path(path g, position position, pen p=currentpen, real size=0,
                   real angle=arrowangle)
    {
      if(size == 0) size=arrowsize(p);
      angle *= arrowhookfactor;
      bool relative=position.relative;
      real position=position.position.x;
      if(relative) position=reltime(g,position);
      path r=subpath(g,position,0);
      pair x=point(r,0);
      real t=arctime(r,size);
      pair y=point(r,t);
      path base=y+2*size*I*dir(r,t)--y-2*size*I*dir(r,t);
      path left=rotate(-angle,x)*r;
      path right=rotate(angle,x)*r;
      real[] T=arrowbasepoints(base,left,right);
      pair denom=point(right,T[1])-y;
      real factor=denom != 0 ? length((point(left,T[0])-y)/denom) : 1;
      path left=rotate(-angle,x)*r;
      path right=rotate(angle*factor,x)*r;
      real[] T=arrowbasepoints(base,left,right);
      left=subpath(left,0,T[0]);
      right=subpath(right,T[1],0);
      pair pl0=point(left,0), pl1=relpoint(left,1);
      pair pr0=relpoint(right,0), pr1=relpoint(right,1);
      pair M=(pl1+pr0)/2;
      pair v=barb*unit(M-pl0);
      pl1=pl1+v; pr0=pr0+v;
      left=pl0{dir(-dir+degrees(M-pl0))}..pl1--M;
      right=M--pr0..pr1{dir(dir+degrees(pr1-M))};
      return left--y--cycle;
    };
  return oa;
}
arrowhead EdgeHookHead=EdgeHookHead();


arrowhead EdgeSimpleHead(real dir=arrowdir, real barb=arrowbarb)
{
  arrowhead oa;
  oa.head=new path(path g, position position, pen p=currentpen, real size=0,
                   real angle=arrowangle)
    {
      if(size == 0) size=arrowsize(p);
      bool relative=position.relative;
      real position=position.position.x;
      if(relative) position=reltime(g,position);
      path r=subpath(g,position,0);
      pair x=point(r,0);
      real t=arctime(r,size);
      pair y=point(r,t);
      path base=y+2*size*I*dir(r,t)--y-2*size*I*dir(r,t);
      path left=rotate(-angle,x)*r;
      path right=rotate(angle,x)*r;
      real[] T=arrowbasepoints(base,left,right);
      pair denom=point(right,T[1])-y;
      real factor=denom != 0 ? length((point(left,T[0])-y)/denom) : 1;
      path left=rotate(-angle,x)*r;
      path right=rotate(angle*factor,x)*r;
      real[] T=arrowbasepoints(base,left,right);
      return subpath(left,T[0],0);
    };
  return oa;
}
arrowhead EdgeSimpleHead=EdgeSimpleHead();


private real position(position position, real size, path g, bool center)
{
  bool relative=position.relative;
  real position=position.position.x;
  if(relative) {
    position *= arclength(g);
    if(center) position += 0.5*size;
    position=arctime(g,position);
  } else if(center)
    position=arctime(g,arclength(subpath(g,0,position))+0.5*size);
  return position;
}

arrowbar EdgeArrows(arrowhead head=EdgeHead,real size=0, real angle=arrowangle,
                    filltype filltype=FillDraw, position position=EndPoint,
                    real space=infinity)
{
  return new bool(picture pic, path g, pen p, margin margin) {
    pair direction;
    real sg=sgn(dot(N,space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2)));
    space = (space == infinity) ? 2*linewidth(p) : space/2;
    if (sg>=0)
      {
        direction=-space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2);
        sg=1;
      }
    else direction=space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2);
    picture tpic;
    tpic.add(new void (frame f, transform t) {
        drawarrow(f,head,t*shift(inverse(t)*(-direction))*g,p,
              size,sg*angle,filltype,position,true,margin,false);
        drawarrow(f,head,t*shift(inverse(t)*direction)*reverse(g),p,
              size,sg*angle,filltype,position,true,margin,false);
      });
    tpic.addPath(g,p);
    real sz=size;
    real gle=angle;
    filltype fl=filltype;
    addArrow(tpic,head,g,p,sz,gle,fl,position(position,size,g,false));
    add(pic,tpic);
    return false;
  };
};

arrowbar EdgeArrows=EdgeArrows();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 05/05/2016:**

Sorry for my first answer. You're right the routine respects the order except in the vertical one.
In fact the order choice depends only the scalar product of the normal at the midpoint of the path and the vector`(0,1)`. In the vertical case there is only one choice. So I modified the routine.

```
arrowbar EdgeArrows(arrowhead head=EdgeHead,real size=0, real angle=arrowangle,
                    filltype filltype=FillDraw, position position=EndPoint,
                    real space=infinity)
{
  return new bool(picture pic, path g, pen p, margin margin) {
    pair direction;
    real sg=sgn(dot(N,space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2)));
    space = (space == infinity) ? 2*linewidth(p) : space/2;
    if (sg>0)
      {
        direction=-space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2);
        sg=1;
      }
    else direction=space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2);
    if (sg==0)
    {
     sg=sgn(dot(N,space*dir(g,length(g)/2)));
     if (sg >0)  direction=-space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2);
     if (sg <0)  direction=space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2);
    }
    picture tpic;
    tpic.add(new void (frame f, transform t) {
        drawarrow(f,head,t*shift(inverse(t)*(-direction))*g,p,
              size,sg*angle,filltype,position,true,margin,false);
        drawarrow(f,head,t*shift(inverse(t)*direction)*reverse(g),p,
              size,sg*angle,filltype,position,true,margin,false);
      });
    tpic.addPath(g,p);
    real sz=size;
    real gle=angle;
    filltype fl=filltype;
    addArrow(tpic,head,g,p,sz,gle,fl,position(position,size,g,false));
    add(pic,tpic);
    return false;
  };
};
```

I made a very few tests, it seems to be ok. I hope that it does not introduce new error and strange behavior.

O.G.

**First answer:**

The goal of the routine is to place at both ends of the path the special `EdgeArrow` (and also to draw a double line). I think that the behavior is the one expected and the placement does not depend of the order of the points. Perhaps it is possible to write such a function (only for a straight line).
As a workaround I propose to add some `RevEdgeArrows` routine to the file.

```
arrowhead RevEdgeHead()
{           
  arrowhead oa;
  oa.head=new path(path g, position position, pen p=currentpen, real size=0,
                   real angle=arrowangle)
    {
      if(size == 0) size=arrowsize(p);
      bool relative=position.relative;
      real position=position.position.x;
      if(relative) position=reltime(g,position);
      path r=subpath(g,position,0.0);
      pair x=point(r,0);
      real t=arctime(r,size);
      pair y=point(r,t);
      path base=y+2*size*I*dir(r,t)--y-2*size*I*dir(r,t);
      path left=rotate(-angle,x)*r;
      real[] T=arrowbasepoints(base,left,r);
      pair denom=point(right,T[1])-y;
      real factor=denom != 0 ? length((point(left,T[0])-y)/denom) : 1;
      path left=rotate(angle,x)*r;
      real[] T=arrowbasepoints(base,left,r);
      return subpath(left,0,T[0])--y--cycle;
    };
  return oa;
}

arrowhead RevEdgeHead=RevEdgeHead();


arrowbar RevEdgeArrows(arrowhead head=RevEdgeHead,real size=0, real angle=arrowangle,
                    filltype filltype=FillDraw, position position=EndPoint,
                    real space=infinity)
{
  return new bool(picture pic, path g, pen p, margin margin) {
    pair direction;
    real sg=sgn(dot(N,space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2)));
    space = (space == infinity) ? 2*linewidth(p) : space/2;
    if (sg>=0)
      {
        direction=-space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2);
        sg=1;
      }
    else direction=space*I*dir(g,length(g)/2);
    picture tpic;
    tpic.add(new void (frame f, transform t) {
        drawarrow(f,head,t*shift(inverse(t)*(direction))*g,p,
              size,sg*angle,filltype,position,true,margin,false);
        drawarrow(f,head,t*shift(inverse(t)*-direction)*reverse(g),p,
              size,sg*angle,filltype,position,true,margin,false);
      });
    tpic.addPath(g,p);
    real sz=size;
    real gle=angle;
    filltype fl=filltype;
    addArrow(tpic,head,g,p,sz,gle,fl,position(position,size,g,false));
    add(pic,tpic);
    return false;
  };
};

arrowbar RevEdgeArrows=RevEdgeArrows();
```

Then

```
import arrows_pi;
size(10cm,10cm);
draw((0.5,0)--(.5,1), EdgeArrows(), p=red);
draw((1,1)--(1,0), RevEdgeArrows(), p=red);
draw((0,0)--(1,0),EdgeArrows(), p=blue);
draw((0,-1)--(1,-1),RevEdgeArrows(), p=blue);
```

gives

[image]

O.G.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend :) It is really useful to me! Unofficial package arrows_pi.asy respects the order of points for horizontal and diagonal arrows. However, it does not respect order of points only for vertical arrows. I don't understand why?

Comment: Thank you OG for the fix.
I have updated the module arrows_pi.asy. Make sure to always download pi-modules from the git repository http://git.piprime.fr/?p=asymptote/pi-packages.git;a=summary Regards